# Excel, variable row index number in VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a model for a refrigeration cycle in excel with COPr as an output. For part of this I need lookup the entalpy which requires pressure AND temperature, so two inputs. I tried to do this with a HLOOKUP function, however when I got the the row-index-number I did not know what to do because this is not a fixed value.

How do I make the row-index number a variable in HLOOKUP (or VLOOKUP) so that it will look up the value of enthalpy for the combination of pressure and temperature that is given?

This is the table that I am using, this should clarify it a bit more:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

The output that I want when pressure and temperature are provided:

[image: Screenshot]

In this case T=-10 C and P=3 Mpa, so I want a function that returns 176.3 for these inputs.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you want, from the data in the table you attached, and the formula you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also place T and P in free cells and use references.

```
=INDEX(C28:AA42,MATCH(3,B28:B42,0),MATCH(-10,C27:AA27,0))
```